# Ext js Tree Lazy Load from MySQL database using Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, tree, extjs4.2

In my application, I am using Node.js as a backend and Extjs as a Frontend.

I need to construct tree in Extjs using Database values which are get from Node.js.

I am able construct the Tree very well.

But there is a problem when the database has more record. In my application have more than '100000' record. So the process of tree construction is Getting long time.

Is there any way to implement Lazy load in Extjs Tree using database ajax call on each node?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best aproach is load only parents node, then capture event click in a parent node to make Ajax call and get child nodes.

I found that : 
[Click event on tree's children/node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722335/click-event-on-trees-children-node)

Use listeners to make Ajax call when item is clicked.

Renderize over 100000 records always take long time, but using listeners in parents nodes you can reduce the records.

I hope this helps !

Comment: @Orilo: can you suggest me some sample code. I too face the same issue with my application.